# Aspect ratio for lat/lon plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial

How do I set the aspect ratio for data plotted in lat/lon to compensate for the effect of latitude?  The goal is to obtain a plot where the separation of data points in the figure is proportional to the real-world distance between them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

latitudes = [30.0, 30.24, 30.44]
longitudes = [18.0, 18.5, 19.0]

mean_lat = numpy.mean(latitudes)
f = 1.0/numpy.cos(mean_lat*numpy.pi/180)

plt.scatter(longitudes, latitudes)
plt.gca().set_aspect(f?  or 1/f?)
```

I only need this for points that are relatively close together, within a degree or two.  I want to keep my axes in degrees, so I don't want to use  a real map projection from `pyproj`.

As much as the answer `f` or `1/f`, I'm interested in the process for how to know that that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `set_aspect(f)`.

How to prove it:

```
longitudes = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
latitudes = [60.0, 61.0, 61.0, 60.0, 60.0]

f = 1.0/numpy.cos(60*numpy.pi/180)

plt.plot(longitudes, latitudes, 'bo-')
plt.gca().set_aspect(f)
```

produces a box that, on screen, is taller than it is wide.  At about 60N, 1 degree of longitude is shorter, in terms of ground distance, than 1 degree of latitude.  So this checks out.